# docker checkout or revert files within docker diff

Tags: docker

for example:

```
docker diff my_nginx

C /etc/apache2/sites-available
C /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
C /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
C /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
C /root
A /root/.bash_history
C /run/apache2
C /tmp
```

But it seems to unconfigure apache2 so it won't start afterward. 
Is there any way to revert those one of changes? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you `docker run` an image, you get a container with a clean filesystem that's identical to its base image.  So in your case you can

```
docker stop my_nginx
docker rm my_nginx
docker run ... # the same command as before
```

For configuration files it's often easier to keep them on the host and use the `docker run -v` option to inject them into a container at startup time.  Manually editing files inside containers tends to not be sustainable: you need to `docker rm` a container for a lot of routine things (changing volume mappings, port mappings, environment variables, upgrading to a newer version of the image) and if you've made a bunch of hand edits inside the container you'll lose that work.

Comment: What I actually need is to revert one of those changes. Sorry to mislead you.

Comment: Docker isn’t a source control system.  You might be able to do something where you `docker run` a new container from the same image and `docker cp` the file from the new container to your host to the old container...but really this just isn’t a workflow Docker is good at.